# undefined Object when i want to dispaly the Recipes

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

This is a project in order to display the recipes and perform many operations on these recipes such as deleting, adding and modifying the same as for presenting recipes
But when viewing the recipes I have many problems, including:

```
                   [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read 
                   property 'title' of undefined"
                   TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

How can i solve the Problem?

Through this file, the recipes are presented in addition to calling the functions in the store.
Recipe:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout row wrap v-if="loading">
      <v-flex xs12 class="text-xs-center">
        <v-progress-circular
          indeterminate
          class="primary--text"
          :width="7"
          :size="70"
          >
        </v-progress-circular>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
    <v-layout row wrap v-else>
      <v-flex x12>
        <v-card>
          <!-- <v-card-title> -->
          <v-card-text>
            <h4 class="btn-style mt-4 mb-4 font">
              {{ recipe.title }}
            </h4>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <app-edit-recipe-details :recipe="recipe"></app-edit-recipe-details>
            <v-img height="530px" :src="recipe.imageUrl" class="mb-4"></v-img>

            <div class="btn-style mb-6">
              {{ recipe.description }}
            </div>
            <div v-for="ing in recipe.ingredients" :key="ing.id">
              {{ ing.Name }} {{ ing.Quantity }}
              <v-btn class="green darken-1  color mb-5 ml-4 mr-4 pl-50">
                <v-icon class="green darken-1 btn-style">mdi-plus</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </div>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      //Here we put Getter
      'loadedRecipe',
      'loadedingredient',
      'loading'
    ]),
    recipe() {
      const loadedRecipe = this.$store.dispatch('loadedRecipe',this.id);
      console.log("We loaded a recipe with value : ", loadedRecipe);
      return loadedRecipe;
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
.btn-style {
  color: #43a047;
}
.color {
  color: #fafafa;
}
.deleteColorIcon {
  color: #e53935;
}
.font {
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
```

And through this file, many of the necessary functions are performed in other components.
store.js:

```
import image1 from "../../assets/img/image1.jpg";
import image2 from "../../assets/img/image2.jpg";
import image3 from "../../assets/img/image3.jpg";
import image4 from "../../assets/img/image4.jpg";
const state = {
  loadedingredients: [
    { id: "1", Name: "Sugar", Quantity: "5kg" },
    { id: "2", Name: "Sugar", Quantity: "5kg" },
    { id: "3", Name: "Sugar", Quantity: "5kg" },
  ],
  loadedRecipes: [
    {
      imageUrl: image3,
      id: "3",
      title: "Homemade Burger",
      description:
        "Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor seats plus patio"
      // loadedingredients
    },
    {
      imageUrl: image1,
      id: "1",
      title: "Cake",
      description:
        "Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor seats plus patio"
      // loadedingredients
    },
    {
      imageUrl: image4,
      id: "4",
      title: "Salad",
      description:
        "Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor seats plus patio"
      // loadedingredients
    },
    {
      imageUrl: image2,
      id: "2",
      title: "Kabseh",
      description:
        "Small plates, salads & sandwiches - an intimate setting with 12 indoor seats plus patio"
      //  loadedingredients
    },
  ],
  user: [{ name: "Hiba", email: "Hiba69@gmail.com", password: "123442321325" }],
  loading: false,
};
const mutations= {
    createRecipe(state, payload) {
        // Vue.set(state, 'loadedRecipes', [...state.loadedRecipes, payload])
        // console.log('Recipe to adad recipe.js',payload)
        state.loadedRecipes.push(payload.recipeData);
      },
      createIngredients(state, payload) {
        // Vue.set(state, 'loadedRecipes', [...state.loadedRecipes, payload])
        state.loadedingredients.push(payload);
      },
      delete_recipe(state, id) {
        let index = state.loadedRecipes.findIndex((recipe) => recipe.id == id);
        state.loadedRecipes.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("Deleted Successfully");
      },
      delete_ingredient(state, id) {
        let index = state.loadedingredients.findIndex(
          (ingredient) => ingredient.id == id
        );
        state.loadedingredients.splice(index, 1);
        console.log("Deleted Successfully");
      },
      updateRecipe(state, payload) {
        const recipe = state.loadedRecipes.find((recipe) => {
          return recipe.id == payload.id;
        });
        if (payload.title) {
          recipe.title = payload.title;
        }
        if (payload.description) {
          recipe.description = payload.description;
        }
      },
      updateingredient(state,payload) {
        const ingredient = state.loadedingredients.find((ingredient)=>{
          return ingredient.id == payload.id;
        });
        if(payload.ingredientsQuantity){
          ingredient.ingredientsQuantity=payload.ingredientsQuantity
        }
      },
      setLoading(state, payload) {
        state.loading = payload;
      }
}
const actions = {
    createRecipe:({commit},payload)=>{
        commit('createRecipe',payload)
    },
    delete_recipe:({commit})=>{
        commit('delete_recipe')
    },
    updateRecipeData({ commit }, payload) {
        // commit('setLoading',true)
        const updateObj = {};
        if (payload.title) {
          updateObj.title == payload.title;
        }
        if (payload.description) {
          updateObj.description == payload.description;
        }
        commit("updateRecipe", payload);
        localStorage.setItem("updateRecipe", this.loadedRecipes);
      },
      updateIngredientData({ commit }, payload) {
        // commit('setLoading',true)
        const updateObj = {};
        if (payload.ingredientsQuantity) {
          updateObj.ingredientsQuantity == payload.ingredientsQuantity;
        }
        commit("updateingredient", payload);
        localStorage.setItem("updateingredient", this.loadedingredients);
      }
};
const getters = {
    loadedRecipes: (state) => {
        return state.loadedRecipes
          .sort((RecipeA, RecipeB) => {
            return RecipeA.id > RecipeB.id;
          })
          .map((aRec) => {
            aRec["ingredients"] = [...state.loadedingredients];
            return aRec;
          });
      },
      loadedingredients: (state) => {
        return state.loadedingredients.sort((ingredientA, ingredientB) => {
          return ingredientA.Quantity > ingredientB.Quantity;
        });
      },
      featuredRecipes: (getters) => {
        return getters.loadedRecipes.slice(0, 5);
      },
      loadedRecipe: (state) => {
        return (recipeId) => {
          return state.loadedRecipes.find((recipe) => {
            return recipe.id === recipeId;
          });
        };
      },
      loadedingredient: (state) => {
        return (ingredientId) => {
          return state.loadedRecipes.find((ingredient) => {
            return ingredient.id === ingredientId;
          });
        };
      }
};
export default{
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution with your current implementation would be to replace the `v-else` by `v-else-if="recipe !== undefined"` (or using a computed method `v-else-if="recipeIsLoaded"`) inside your v-layout.

Comment: I still have this:>>>>
We loaded a recipe with value :  undefined>>>
I don't know why it's undefined.